PyCharm does not display Chinese characters although UTF-8 encoding
I have just switched to using PyCharm a couple of days ago. I have installed the community edition on a Linux virtual machine (i.e. Ubuntu 9.4.0). This is the About of my installed Pycharm:
PyCharm 2024.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-241.14494.241, built on March 28, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+8-b1207.12 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.4.0-131-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 72
Registry:
  ide.experimental.ui=true
Current Desktop: Undefined

All the Chinese characters in my Python scripts look like this:

I have checked that the encoding of the files is UTF-8 in the project setting, but it does not seem to be taken into account.
I have also tried some solutions suggesting changing the font of the editor or adding an environment variable like in this question but these didn't work (the latter one is more for the console rather than for the code files).
To give more details, I am sshing the VM in which Pycharm is installed from a Windows machine through Mobaxterm.
I have installed Pycharm for Windows on my Windows machine and opened the same files. It perfectly displays the characters. This is making me think it is about the OS.
Any tips?
